# How does a transistor sweep generator work?

Tags: transistors, oscilloscope, trigger

In particular I'm wondering about oscilloscope sweep generators, but the concept I don't understand remains the same for any type, which is, what does the triggering? I know a transistor can be switched on and off incredibly fast, but I've got a sweep generator in front of me that consists of 2 transistors and some resistors and capacitors. No matter how many components you have in a sweep generation circuit, that command to turn on and off that gets sent to the transistors, it's got to come from somewhere. To my knowledge, a transistor can only switch as fast as it's being told to switch by an on and off base current. What kind of component originates this?

I was under the impression that Q14 and Q15 were the sweep generator. But I don't understand what is actually generating the fast signal responsible for the creation of this sweep.

[image]

Comment: Please share the schematic of the circuit you mentioned.

Comment: 2 transistors, some resistors, and some capacitors sounds like some type of oscillator circuit to me.

Comment: Is this an oscillatior? I thought Q14 and Q15 were the sweep generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sweep ramp is controlled by a 10.0V ref and a manual selector with 1M or 2M and rotary cap. decade selector. The Pullup on Q15-c at 160V feeds the selected caps and the large resistor values create the positive ramp. The p-JFET Q14 buffers the ramp and a small resistor ratio pulls it down with the -10V Vref thru the pot to NPN Q15-b and when it reaches > 0.7V turns on abruptly with a fast negative impulse to end the ramp.

Other parts to the left initiate the holdoff, trigger and 1-shot sweep thru diodes and tiny impulse reduction caps.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger level and mode - the signal generating the "start" for the sweep, is generated by Q1 to Q7 inclusive. I haven't analysed it well enough to follow the logic levels and the diode switch D1-3 but this must (a) reset the charge on the capacitor by shorting it out before the sweep, (b) then go high impedance (reverse biassed) to allow the integrator to generate the sweep waveform.

Once allowed to start, a variable current source (actually not infinite impedance but 1 or 2 Megohms R109,110 from a variable voltage VR107A is integrated in a selection of capacitors S103,C113 etc by Q14 (source follower, buffer) and Q15 (gain) giving a sawtooth on Q15 collector which is the sweep itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some triggers used Esaki diodes --- aka tunnel diiodes --- with their region of bi_stability.

Others use positive-feedback circuits, where 2 gain-devices (tubes, transistors) implement a loop. The delay around the loop, and the gain around the loop, determine the "snapiness".

With gain of 4X per device, or 16x around the loop, an input ony 1 millivolt past threshold cause 16mv after 1 loop, 256 mv after 2 loops, and 4.096 volts after 3 loops.

And 4 volts is a fine delta_V to control even vacuum tube differential pairs ( called long-tail-pairs).